# UI Bootstrap and Laravel Blade Templating

Tags: laravel-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using UI Bootstrap in my project : [UI Bootstrap](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

**Problem** : I cannot handle javascript `<script>` tags with blade templating. Getting internal server error (500)

Here's my **Views** path :

**Views**

- includes
- layouts
- pages

Here's my **includes/head.blade.php** file :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="Scotch">

<title>Title</title>

{{ HTML::style('../public/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}
{{ HTML::script('//public/js/jquery-1.11.1.js')}}
```

Here's my **layouts/home.blade.php** file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
<head>
    @include('includes.head')
    {{ HTML::script('//public/js/ui.bootstrap.min.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('//public/js/angular.min.js')}}
    {{ HTML::script('//public/js/example.js')}}
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

    <header class="row">
        @include('includes.header')
    </header>

    <div id="main" class="row">
        @yield('content')
    </div>

    <footer class="row">
        @include('includes.footer')
    </footer>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's my **pages/home.blade.php** file :

```
@extends('layouts.home')
@section('content')
    <div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="myModalContent.html">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                        <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
                <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </script>

        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
        <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
    </div>
@stop
```

Here's my **public/js/example.js** file :

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalDemoCtrl', function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

  $scope.open = function (size) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      size: size,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected = selectedItem;
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
});

// Please note that $modalInstance represents a modal window (instance) dependency.
// It is not the same as the $modal service used above.

angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope, $modalInstance, items) {

  $scope.items = items;
  $scope.selected = {
    item: $scope.items[0]
  };

  $scope.ok = function () {
    $modalInstance.close($scope.selected.item);
  };

  $scope.cancel = function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

Here's my ui.bootstrap.min.js injection :

[image]

Now here's the problem :

I think in **pages/home.blade.php** file, i am having problem codes between `<script></script>` tags.

Check this out :

[image: Problem]

And here's the error i get (Sorry, the default language is Turkish)

[image]

As like i said, my purpose is using **both UI Bootstrap and laravel blade templating.**

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Try the web page in Chrome, open the Web Inspector toolbar, click the Network tab, and look for the request that has the 500 Internal Server Error. If you click the preview tab, it will give you the error message Laravel is returning.

Comment: @MartinBean sorry but it says "Failed to load response data". Got any other ideas ?

Comment: Install laravel debugbar to see more about the error https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar

Comment: I don't know much about angular but are you sure the angular controller is routed properly? Like the route that is being called exists? Can you access it directly outside of the container that references it? Sorry - it's been a while since I started learning angular.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear if this is your *only* issue, but both Angular and Blade templates use the same tokens for denoting the begin / end of interpolated areas, i.e. `{{` and `}}`.  If you want to use them together, you will need to change one of them to something else, otherwise your angular code will be interpreted by Blade on the server and cause a 500 server error.

In Blade this looks like:

```
Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>'); 
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');
```

In Angular, it would look like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});
```

Comment: The problem is something else. I am trying to use ui bootstrap without blade templating, it is still not working. But your answer will be helpful when i solve the problem. I will be keeping in touch.

Comment: Check your network tab to make sure the UI Bootstrap assets are loading correctly.  Looking at how you're trying to pull them in above: `'//public/js/ui.bootstrap.min.js'` > you shouldn't have to include the `public` directory in that

Comment: Thank you @watcher.  I am mobile now, but i will let you know tomorrow. Thank you for feedback.